# Avoiding Locking Contention on DB2 zOS

Tags: database, db2, triggers, zos

I want to place DB2 Triggers for Insert, Update and Delete on DB2 Tables heavily used in parallel online Transactions. The tables are shared by several members on a Sysplex, DB2 Version 10.
In each of the DB2 Triggers I want to insert a row into a central table and have **one** background process calling a Stored Procedure to read this table every second to process the newly inserted rows, ordered by sequence of the insert (sequence number or timestamp).
I'm very concerned about DB2 Index locking contention and want to make sure that I do not introduce Deadlocks/Timeouts to the applications with these Triggers.

Obviously I would take advantage of DB2 Features to reduce locking like rowlevel locking, but still see no real good approach how to avoid index contention.

I see three different options to select the newly inserted rows.

1. Put a sequence number in the table and the store the last processed sequence number in the background process. I would do the following select Statement:

SELECT COLUMN_1, .... Column_n
FROM CENTRAL_TABLE
WHERE SEQ_NO > 'last-seq-number'
ORDER BY SEQ_NO;

Locking Level must be CS to avoid selecting uncommited rows, which will be later rolled back.
I think I need one Index on the table with SEQ_NO ASC

Pro: Background process only reads rows and makes no updates/deletes (only shared locks)
Neg: Index contention because of ascending key used.
I can clean-up processed records later (e.g. by rolling partions).

2. Put a Status field in the table (processed and unprocessed) and change the Select as follows:

SELECT COLUMN_1, .... Column_n
FROM CENTRAL_TABLE
WHERE STATUS = 'unprocessed'
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;

Later I would update the STATUS on the selected rows to "processed"
I think I need an Index on STATUS
Pro: No ascending sequence number in the index and no direct deletes 
Cons: Concurrent updates by online transactions and the background process
Clean-up would happen in off-hours

3. DELETE the processed records instead of the status field update.

SELECT COLUMN_1, .... Column_n
FROM CENTRAL_TABLE
ORDER BY TIMESTAMP;

Since the table contains very few records, no index is required which could create a hot spot.
Also I think I could SELECT with Isolation Level UR, because I would detect potential uncommitted data on the later delete of this row.
For a Primary Key index I could use GENERATE_UNIQUE,which is random an not ascending. 
Pro: No Index hot spot and the Inserts can be spread across the tablespace by random UNIQUE_ID
Con: Tablespace scan and sort on every call of the Stored Procedure and deleting records in parallel to the online inserts.

Looking forward what the community thinks about this problem. This must be a pretty common problem e.g. SAP should have a similar issue on their Batch Input tables.
I tend to favour Option 3, because it avoids index contention.
May be there is still another solution in your minds out there.

Comment: Theoretical performance tuning is usually futile. How many rows do you expect your "background process" will handle every second?

Comment: First, I'd use a timestamp regardless, probably with an index (this is less about initial performance, and more for sane application design).  What version are you on?  If possible, look into the `OLD_TABLE` data-change table reference (which means a `SELECT` would give you the rows deleted by a `DELETE` statement, essentially).  Actually, I'm more worried about what happens if your process fails while attempting to deal with individual records.

Comment: The Triggers would Insert about 100 rows per second with and 200 per second at peak times. Estimating 10-20 Inserts per LUW, I look at about 10 Tps. Occationally there will be Batch mass updates happening via direct SQL (Update a specific code in a Table to a new value). This could fire 50,000 - 100,000 Triggers in one shot, but from a  single batch job/LUW at night.

Comment: Regarding the Timestamp. I fully agree, much better than a sequence number. However I'm still worried to put an Index on Timestamp, all concurrent Transactions would insert more or less the same Timestamp values at the end of the b-tree. I'm not sure how DB2 would synchronize the index updates and what the max rate would be to update the index in strictly ascending order of a Timestamp value. As a Primary Key I would still use GENERATE_UNIQUE Key, which is random and unique across a Sysplex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are going to have numerous performance problems with your various solutions.
(I know premature optimazation is a sin, but experience tells us that some things are just not going to work in a busy system).

You should be able to use DB2s autoincrement feature to get your sequence number, with little or know performance implications.

For the rest perhaps you should look at a Queue based solution.

Have your trigger drop the operation (INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE) and the keys of the row into a MQ queue,

Then have a long running backgound task (in CICS?) do your post processing as its processing one update at a time you should not trip over yourself.  Having a single loaded and active task with the ability to batch up units of work should give you a throughput in the order of 3 to 5 hundred updates a second.

Comment: MQ was also my first choice.

Comment: My concerns for using MQ. Besides the online updates the will be dynamic SQL Batch updates (single SQL Statements doing mass updates on certain values). The Batch Jobs use TSO attachment. I learned form IBM that the MQSSEND API is not Transactional, if the DB2 Transaction is not running under CICS or IMS/DC. If the Trigger is fired from a TSO Batch Attachment the Messages are always send, even if the LUW is rolled back. To avoid this, the Trigger need to call an External Stored Procedure running in a WLM Address Space and have the Transaction coordinated by RSS.

Comment: The Organisation I'm working with has never done the set-up of a WLM to make a 2PC between DB2 and MQ. Also I hoped to keep the logic within a native Trigger running in the DB2 Address Space only. Another issue on MQ would be performance, because each fired Trigger would have to do an Open, Put, and Close for each individual message. There will be 10-20 messages send for each LUW. This could be a performace and ressource consumption issue.